# Optimal database structure for entries in flexible category/subcategory system?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to store reviews in a flexible system of categories and subcategories, and am currently in the process of designing the database structure for that. I have an idea how to do that, but I'm not entirely sure if it couldn't be done more elegant and/or efficient. These are my thoughts - if anybody can comment on if/how this can be improved I'd be really grateful.

(To keep this post concise, I only list the important field for the tables)

1.) The reviews are stored in the table "reviews". It has the following fields:

```
id: uniquite ID, auto-incrementing.
title: the title that will show up in <head><title>, etc.
stub: a version of the title without spaces, special chars, etc. so it can be part of the URL/URI
text: the actual content
```

2.) All categories are in the same table "categories"

```
id: unique ID, auto-incrementing.
title: the full title/name of the categorie how it will be output on the website
stub: version of the title that will be shown in the URL/URI.
parent_id: if this is a subcategory, here is the categories.id of the parent category. Else this is 0.
order_number: simple number to order the categories by (for display in the navigation menu)
```

3.) Now I need an indicator which reviews are in what categories. The can be in multiple. My first idea was to add a "review_list" field to the categories and have it contain all reviews.id's that should be in this category. However I think that adding and removing reviews from categories would be a hassle and "unelegant". So my current idea is to have a table "review_in_category" and have an entry for every review-category relation. The structure is:

```
id: Unique ID, auto-increment. 
review_id: the reviews.id 
category_id: the categories.id
```

So if a review is in 3 different categories it would result in 3 entries in the "review_in_category" table.

The idea is, that when a user opens www.mydomain.de/animation/sci-fi/ the wrapper script will break up the URL into its parts. If it finds more than one category with category.stub = "sci-fi", it will check which of those has a parent category with the stub "animation". Once the correct category is identified (most the time the stubs are unique anyway so this check can be skipped) I want to SELECT all review_id's from "review_in_category" where the category_id matches the the one determined by the wrapper script. All the review_id's are put into an array. A loop will iterate through this array and compose the SELECT statement for listing all review titles (and create links to them using the stub values) by "SELECT title, stub FROM reviews WHERE id=review_list[$counter]" and then add "OR id=review_list[$counter]" until the array is completely travelled.

SO my questions are:
- Is the method my creating a single SELECT statement with potentially a large number of "OR id=" parts an "elegent" and/or efficient way to handle this situation or are there better variants?
- Does using a "taxonomy"-style table (review_in_category) make sense or would it be better to store the "membership"/"relation" directly in the reviews or category tables?
- Any other thoughts... I just started to learn this stuff and appreciate any feedback.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design looks sound.

To retrieve all reviews in a category, you should use a join:

```
SELECT reviews.title, reviews.stub FROM reviews, review_in_category WHERE reviews.id = review_in_category.review_id AND category_id = $category
```